# Android ANR WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop

Tags: android, performance, java-native-interface

I'm having a very hard time debugging an Android ANR problem.

This is what I get in logcat:

```
 I/art﹕ Thread[2,tid=29718,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaf40e400,peer=0x12c39080,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
```

Heres what I get in the traces.txt file

```
    "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12c57080 self=0xaf40e400
  | sysTid=29718 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0xafb18d80
  | state=R schedstat=( 32478966 17635623 73 ) utm=1 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xb466d000-0xb466f000 stackSize=1012KB
  | held mutexes= "thread list lock" "mutator lock"(exclusive held)
  native: #00 pc 00004640  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
  native: #01 pc 00002e8d  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
  native: #02 pc 002453c1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+68)
  native: #03 pc 00229f47  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+146)
  native: #04 pc 00232ddf  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+142)
  native: #05 pc 00218da7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+66)
  native: #06 pc 0021ed13  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit()+774)
  native: #07 pc 0021f3cb  /system/lib/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+322)
  native: #08 pc 000137bb  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
  native: #09 pc 0001189b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
  (no managed stack frames)
```

Does anyone know what can usually cause these sorts of errors?  I can't pinpoint it to any particular line of code but it does seem to happen on starting the app sometimes.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out Strict Mode? It's exceptionally useful in tracking down these types of ANR problems. There's a great video on it here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGrXdxpWgyY&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=23

Comment: Thanks Colt, the video was terrific, super informative! I will do Strict Mode next. I've primarily been debugging by isolating code, and what I found is that ANR's seems to be exacerbated by Google Maps. I'm embedding a map fragment inside another fragment and accessing it through getChildFragmentManager(). Sometimes when I first initialize the fragment there is a noticeable delay that triggers an ANR.

Comment: In case anyone wants to know, this seems to have resolved itself when I upgraded from 5.0 to 5.1

Comment: @Potato what did you upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1? Thank you!